# Bison/flex waits for input after recognizing a rule

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, flex-lexer, bisonc++

I have the following files for lexical and syntactic analysis:

**lexico.l**

```
%{
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string>   
    using namespace std;
    extern int yylex();
    #include "sintactico.h" // to get token types from Bison
%}
%option noyywrap
vfit1                       (?i:ff)
vfit2                       (?i:bf)
vfit3                       (?i:wf)
%%
#(.)*                       { printf("COMENTARIO\n"); }
[ \t\n]                     { /* Ignorar espacios en blanco */ }
[0-9]+                      { printf("INT\n"); yylval.sval = new string(yytext); return INT; }
\"([^\\\"]|\\.)*\"          { printf("STRING\n"); /*return STRING*/ }
(?i:mkdisk)                 { printf("MKDISK\n"); return MKDISK; }
(?i:size)                   { printf("SIZE\n");  yylval.sval = new string(yytext); return SIZE; }
(?i:unit)                   { printf("UNIT\n");  yylval.sval = new string(yytext); return UNIT; }
(?i:path)                   { printf("PATH\n");  yylval.sval = new string(yytext); return PATH; }
(?i:fit)                    { printf("FIT\n");  yylval.sval = new string(yytext); return FIT; }
-                           { printf("GUION\n"); return GUION; }
=                           { printf("IGUAL\n"); return IGUAL; }
{vfit1}|{vfit2}|{vfit3}     { printf("VFIT\n");  yylval.sval = new string(yytext); return VFIT; }
[bkmKBM]                    { printf("VUNIT\n"); yylval.sval = new string(yytext); return VUNIT; }
[a-zA-Z0-9/._]+             { printf("VSTRING\n"); yylval.sval = new string(yytext); return VSTRING; }
.                           { printf("ERROR\n"); }
%%
```

**sintactico.y**

```
%{  
    #include <cstdio>   
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    using namespace std;
    map<string, string> opc;
    // Declare stuff from Flex that Bison needs to know about:
    extern int yylex();
    //extern int yyparse();
    extern FILE *yyin;
    #include "lexico.h"
    #include "cadena.h"

    void yyerror(const char *s);

    void test_map(){        
        cout << "opc.size() is " << opc.size() << endl;
        for(auto it : opc){
            cout << "*************************\n";
            cout << it.first << endl;
            cout << it.second << endl;
            cout << "*************************\n";
        }
    }       
%}

%union{
    int ival;       
    char cval;
    std::string *sval;  
}

%token        MKDISK RMDISK FDISK MOUNT UNMOUNT 
%token        TYPE DELETE 
%token        NAME ADD ID STRING GUION IGUAL

%token <sval> SIZE FIT PATH UNIT 
%token <sval> VSTRING INT VFIT VUNIT

%type <sval>  val_path

%%

axioma:             instr{
                        cout << "Finaliza" << endl;
                    };  

instr:              mkdisk{
                        analisis_mkdisk(opc);
                    };

mkdisk:             MKDISK list_mkdisk;

list_mkdisk:        list_mkdisk opc_mkdisk
                |   opc_mkdisk;

opc_mkdisk:         size
                |   fit
                |   unit
                |   path;

size:               GUION SIZE IGUAL INT{
                        cout << *$2 << ": " << *$4 << endl;
                        a_minus(*$2);                   
                        opc[*$2] = *$4;
                        delete $4;                      
                    };

fit:                GUION FIT IGUAL VFIT{
                        cout << *$2 << ": " << *$4 << endl;
                        a_minus(*$2); 
                        a_minus(*$4);
                        opc[*$2] = *$4; delete $4;
                    };

unit:               GUION UNIT IGUAL VUNIT{
                        cout << *$2 << ": " << *$4 << endl;
                        a_minus(*$2);
                        a_minus(*$4);
                        opc[*$2] = *$4; delete $4;
                    };

path:               GUION PATH IGUAL val_path{
                        cout << *$2 << ": " << *$4 << endl;
                        a_minus(*$2);
                        opc[*$2] = *$4; delete $4;
                    };

val_path:           VSTRING;                

%%
```

The following entry must be correct: mkdisk -size=20. The code for the size rule runs, however, in order for the code for the instr rule to run I have to press CTRL + D. Why does that happen? What is missing to add to the code? Is the parser lexical or syntactic?

EDIT: I removed the EOL token from the parser.
What I don't really understand is, how does the parser know that the entry has finished? After entering the mkdisk -size = 20 command in the console, press the ENTER key. How do I tell Bison that my entry ends with ENTER? Why does the analyzer wait for an entry to finish the analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says here:

```
mkdisk:             MKDISK list_mkdisk EOL;
```

So `mkdisk` needs an `EOL` token in order to be complete, and it won't be reduced until it's complete.

But nowhere does your lexer return an `EOL` token. Assuming that `EOL` means "end of line", it would be logical for `\n`  to produce an `EOL` token. But we have

```
[ \t\n]                     { /* Ignorar espacios en blanco */ }
```

So no EOL token, and no reduction. I don't see any way that the `instr` rule could run; if you enter an EOF, then the parser should report a syntax error from the missing EOL. But maybe I'm misunderstanding your error report.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Well, the code I was supposed to put here doesn't have EOL. It was just a mistake. However, you are right in what you wrote. If my parser only works with console input, I wouldn't need to use EOF, right?

Comment: @enrique260619: I'm honestly not sure what you mean. Perhaps this would be easier in Spanish (see [es.so]). Bison parsers do not always wait for a lookahead token, unlike parsers produced by other parser generators, but it is not always evident when a token is the end of a rule. Without the `EOL`, the `mkdisk` production can continue to accept more tokens as long as they are in `list_mkdisk`, so it cannot be reduced until the parser reads a token which is not a valid option token (such as another `mkdisk`). So you don't need an EOF, but you need something.

Comment: @enrique260619: If you're intending this to run from the command line, you probably do want to terminate your commands with an EOL. So the mistake wasn't that EOL was in the grammar. The mistake was that your lexer never sends an EOL. (And for the future, it's not considered polite to edit a question in a way which makes answers invalid. Please don't do that. If you accidentally ask the "wrong" question and it get answered, you should ask a different question rather than change the one you already asked.)+